# Passing image parameter c# windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, parameters

Hi I'm trying to pass an image as a parameter within a Windows Phone app. The user is able to click a thumbnail of an image and then be directed to a new page with a full size copy of that image.

I have tried the following but get a red line error under "image.SetSource(e.OriginalSource);" below? Obviously then the gesture event is not suitable but I don't know what else I could use?

Here is the event code when the user clicks on one of the images. The image is nameed flickr1Image.

```
         private void flickr1Image_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource != null)
        {
         //Edits
        if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("Image"))
                if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Image"] != null)
                    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove("Image");
                    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage image = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                    image.SetSource(e.OriginalSource);
                    this.flickr1Image.Source = image;
                    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Image"] = image;
        }
    }
```

Below is the code executed to load the image into the page. I was hoping the code below would work of all images passed to it?

```
         protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        image = (BitmapImage)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Image"];
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove("Image");
        this.flick.Source = image;
    }
```

Help please

many thanks

Comment: Your sender is Image. Cast sender as Image and Set BitmpaImage Source to sender Source.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would share my solution to the problem above in case anyone else needs it...

Add a class with static methods as below:

```
     class ImageStore
     {
         private static ImageStore current = new ImageStore();

         public static ImageStore Current
         {
             get { return current; }
         }

     public BitmapImage Image { get; set; } 

     }
```

Then added this to the event:

```
    private void flickr1Image_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageStore.Current.Image = (BitmapImage)flickr1Image.Source;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/flickrPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Then this on the recieving page:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        flick.Source = ImageStore.Current.Image;
    }
```

The image can be retrieved anywhere whenever I need it..

...Simple